# Enunciate validation failing

Tags: java, spring, maven, enunciate

I'm getting the following error while running `mvn -e enunciate:docs` on a project:

```
error: [core] java.lang.StackTraceElement: A TypeDefinition must have a no-arg constructor or be annotated with a factory method.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.enunciate:maven-enunciate-plugin:1.26:docs (default-cli) on project enunciate_doc_test: Problem assembling the enunciate app. org.codehaus.enunciate.apt.ModelValidationException: There were validation errors -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.enunciate:maven-enunciate-plugin:1.26:docs (default-cli) on project enunciate_doc_test: Problem assembling the enunciate app.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Problem assembling the enunciate app.
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.DocsMojo.execute(DocsMojo.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.enunciate.EnunciateException: org.codehaus.enunciate.apt.ModelValidationException: There were validation errors
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.apt.EnunciateAnnotationProcessor.process(EnunciateAnnotationProcessor.java:732)
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.apt.EnunciateAnnotationProcessor.process(EnunciateAnnotationProcessor.java:118)
    at com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessors$CompositeAnnotationProcessor.process(AnnotationProcessors.java:60)
    at com.sun.tools.apt.comp.Apt.main(Apt.java:454)
    at com.sun.tools.apt.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:258)
    at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Main.java:1102)
    at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Main.java:964)
    at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.processing(Main.java:95)
    at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:85)
    at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate.invokeApt(Enunciate.java:777)
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate.doGenerate(Enunciate.java:366)
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.ConfigMojo$MavenSpecificEnunciate.doGenerate(ConfigMojo.java:646)
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate$Stepper.step(Enunciate.java:1735)
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate$Stepper.stepTo(Enunciate.java:1767)
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.DocsMojo.execute(DocsMojo.java:96)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.enunciate.apt.ModelValidationException: There were validation errors
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.apt.EnunciateAnnotationProcessor.validate(EnunciateAnnotationProcessor.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.apt.EnunciateAnnotationProcessor.getRootModel(EnunciateAnnotationProcessor.java:262)
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.apt.EnunciateAnnotationProcessor.process(EnunciateAnnotationProcessor.java:103)
    ... 35 more
```

None of my java files are mentioned anywhere. Is there any way I can find out which file is causing the problem?

I ran the command with the -X option enabled as well, and the only [DEBUG] messages I got were of the type `[class name] is a potential schema type definition, but we're not going to add it directly to the model. (It could still be indirectly added, though.)`

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: How are you integrating the annotation processor in your build? If it is integrated in the compilation itself, it might just be a compilation issue (i.e. your module does not compile and the annotation processor is confused because the compiler model for a class isn't right). You can check that by disabling the annotation processor (remove the dependency and compile your project)

Answer (score 0):

Enunciate is trying to treat `java.lang.StackTraceElement` as a type definition. You must have an accessor or something that returns an Exception or something. You can have Enunciate output the "reference trail" that you can follow to determine which property Enunciate is following to include `java.lang.StackTraceElement` as a type definition:

```
  <enunciate includeReferenceTrailInErrors="true">
    ...
  </enunciate>
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent for ant? I get build.xml:88: enunciate doesn't support the "includeReferenceTrailInErrors" attribute

Comment: What version of enunciate are you using ?